# How to get address of an excel cell from which a formula is calling the data from?

Tags: excel, formula

As seen [image: here], I am trying to get the cell address of the origin data, without duplicates. The can be done partially by `=address(index match)`. I want `C19` to show the value of `B8` in the above picture.

Comment: I don't know why Mr. Ford edited my post but my original post said that =address match would not work because of the duplicates. i.e. if there are two people with the same grades, it would show the same name for both ranks with the same grade.

Comment: Why do you want the address?  Is it because you want the names to go with the scores and can't because of the duplicates?  Because that can be overcome.

Comment: Plus you can always roll back the edits.

Comment: yes actually. i want the persons' name to show up next to the grades. i was thinking of getting cell address and calling the data of cell next to it.

Comment: Now that you have two answers, please choose the one you used as the correct answer.  You do this by clicking the green check mark by the chosen answer.  It is something only you can do.  It will close the question as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the Name, use [INDEX](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/index-function-0ee99cef-a811-4762-8cfb-a222dd31368a) with [AGGREGATE](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AGGREGATE-function-43B9278E-6AA7-4F17-92B6-E19993FA26DF) providing the *position within* adjusted by the duplicates with [COUNTIF](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/COUNTIF-function-E0DE10C6-F885-4E71-ABB4-1F464816DF34).

If you have to have the cell address, adjust the same AGGREGATE formula to return the actual row on the worksheet but don't use this with [INDIRECT](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-21f8bcfc-b174-4a50-9dc6-4dfb5b3361cd) to achieve the Name.

```
'for the name in C19
=INDEX(A$5:A$12, AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($1:$8)/(B$5:B$12=B19), COUNTIF(B$19:B19, B19)))
'for the cell address in D19
=ADDRESS(AGGREGATE(15, 6, ROW($5:$12)/(B$5:B$12=B19), COUNTIF(B$19:B19, B19)), COLUMN(B:B), 4, 1)
```

Fill down as necessary.

[image: aggregate_first_second_grade]

Comment: I don't know why Mr. Ford edited my post but my original post said that =address match would not work because of the duplicates. i.e. if there are two people with the same grades, it would show the same name for both ranks with the same grade.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Array formula:

```
=INDEX($A$5:$A$12,MATCH(1,IF(($B$5:$B$12=B19)*(COUNTIF($C$18:$C18,$A$5:$A$12)=0),1,0),0))
```

Being an Array formula; copy and paste this into the formula bar for cell C19.  Press Ctrl-Shift-Enter to exit edit mode instead of enter or tab.  If Excel puts `{}` around the formula, it has been properly entered as an array formula.

Then copy down.

[image]